# Display DateOfEdited and DateOfInserted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to add two option in my application which is `disable`and should be hidden in `Create.cshtml` and `Edit.cshtml`
So when user create a new post it should display the date when form is created and when user edit records it should display date when records is edited.
Currenty I added this field in `Model`

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? DatumUnosta { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? DatumPromjene { get; set; }
```

And added this part

```
public ProduzenaGarancija()
{
    DatumUnosta = DateTime.Now;
    DatumPromjene = DateTime.Now;
}
```

In my `Create.cshtml`

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <label>Datum  unosa</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <input asp-for="Garancija.DatumUnosta" id="datum_unosa"
               type="text" disabled class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And Edit.cshtml

```
 <div class="form-group row">
     <div class="col-3">
         <label>Datum  promjene</label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-5">
         <input asp-for="Garancija.DatumPromjene" type="text"
                disabled id="datum_promjene" class="form-control" />
     </div>
 </div>
```

**Application.js** scripts for those two label:

```
$("#datum_unosa").datepicker({
            //dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());

$("#datum_promjene").datepicker({
            //dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Whenever I insert or update record both date has same `datetime field`
Even a couple of minutes when I try to update record `Date of Create` and `Date of Update` has the same value.Does anyone know what is wrong here, and what is the best way to do this ?

[image]

Comment: when do you update the DatumPromjene during your edit?

Comment: After I click Edit button it should store in db automatically when form is edited

Comment: This two field is hidden, so user can not see when form is created and when form is updated, only administrator should see those two field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the model, which is loaded from database (I assume, you haven't showed code for that). Once it is loaded you just show the values. This part probably work (as we have multiple date/times shown).

The part where the problem resides, is **when the values are created**. If you look at this code:

```
public ProduzenaGarancija()
{
    DatumUnosta = DateTime.Now;
    DatumPromjene = DateTime.Now;
}
```

---

In this constructor, you set both times to be `DateTime.Now` and then you keep the time like. But when You update the object `ProduzenaGarancija`, do you also update the property `DatumPromjene`?

One way to do it, is on each property update, call method called e.g. `onUpdate()`, that will do the time update for you:

```
private string mName;
//Some of my property
public string Name
{
    get { return this.mName }
    set
    {
        this.mName = value;
        this.onUpdate();
    }
}

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? DatumPromjene { get; set; }

public void onUpdate()
{
    this.DatumPromjene = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Or, if you don't want to touch your model (especially the properties), you can call this at the end of edit. But then you must remember that at every change you do, you must also change the time:

```
public void EditButton_Clicked(/* Event handlers*/)
{
    var myObject = this.myObject; // get the object from <somewhere>

    myObject.Name = "abc"; /*set properties
    .
    .
    .
     */

    //at the end of edit, you should call either of these rows to change the time
    myObject.onUpdate(); 
    myObject.DatumPromjene = DateTime.Now; 
}
```